# Get refresh_token request throws "App doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy"

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a Project on Google cloud with a single Project.

When configuring the **OAuth Consent Screen**, I have

- added the Sensitive Scope `/auth/drive.readonly`
- added my other email id in `Test users`

When creating the **Client ID for Web application**, I have

- added 2 redirect URIs (let us name them URL-1 and URL-2) (both `https` URLs accessible over the internet).

Now, I made a redirected request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` from my browser `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id={CLIENT-ID}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.readonly&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&state=193&response_type=code&redirect_uri={URL-1}`

It showed the following screen
[image]

and then took to the OAuth consent screen requesting permission for
[image]

where I hit Continue.
I got a request at URL-1 with the state and code. Now I made a `POST` request to `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` with params

```
code={CODE}&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&redirect_uri={URL-2}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

But I get the 400 response with body

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "\nYou can&#39;t sign in to this app because it doesn&#39;t comply with Google&#39;s OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.\n\nYou can let the app developer know that this app doesn&#39;t comply with one or more Google validation rules.\n  "
}
```

I have my app in Test mode and I signed in only with the Test User. But I still get this error. Even tried making the last request from Postman. The result was still the same.

Comment: you need a valid redirect URI.    it needs to be confirmed in Google developer console for your web application.   make sure its https

Comment: As mentioned by DalmTo, my guess is also that the URL is not secure since the rest seems fine. This is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/policy-compliance#use-secure-redirect-uris-javascript-origins). Let us know if that's the case.

Comment: I have 2 redirect URIs added and both of them are publicly hosted https URIs

Comment: That's strange then. Have you [verified ownership](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/policy-compliance#only-use-domains-you-own) of the domains that you are using as redirect?

Comment: Getting the same error even after verifying the domains. However, is domain verification necessary even for Test mode?