# App doesn't comply with Google OAuth policy

Tags: python, google-oauth

I want basic user authentication using Google OAuth2 sign in. I open a browser in my app to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth`, and receive the authentication token at my python server. But if I try to exchange this with an access token, google complains about not complying with the policy, without going into more detail.

> You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.
>
> You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.

I tried it using a simple http request, as well as using their python module with the same result.
The later would complain if https is not available.

This issue sounds related, but the OP had success once while I constantly failed so far. The answers do not help in my case: [Error message "You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70638732/error-message-you-cant-sign-in-to-this-app-because-it-doesnt-comply-with-goog)

My guess is the redirect URI is incorrect, because not escaping it (using colons) result in an uri_mismatch, while sending an escaped, but invalid URI results in the generic error from above.

[There might also be an issue with using this subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74111525/get-refresh-token-request-throws-app-doesnt-comply-with-googles-oauth-2-0-pol) (provided by my vps), but then I do not understand why I received the authentication token just fine, or how I can properly verify that domain. The app is still in testing and therefore not authorized.

I added all redirects in the authorized redirects list.

I'm following this page: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server

```
https%3A//my-subdomain.zap-srv.com%3A8000/login
```

Java client to open the browser:

```java
        // Construct the authorization URL
        String authUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?"
                + "client_id=" + clientId
                + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri
                + "&state=" + "125"
                + "&response_type=code"
                + "&nonce=" + nonce
                + "&scope=openid";

        // Open the authorization URL in the user's default web browser
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(authUrl));
```

Python using their module:

```py
    redirect_uri = "https%3A//my-subdomain.zap-srv.com%3A8000/login"

    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        "client_secret.json", scopes=["openid"], state=state
    )
    flow.redirect_uri = redirect_uri

    flow.fetch_token(code=code, include_client_id=True)
```

Alternative Python using http request with the same result:

```py
    redirect_uri = "https%3A//my-subdomain.zap-srv.com%3A8000/login"

    # Set up the request parameters
    url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
    data = {
        "code": code,
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    }

    # Send the request and retrieve the access token
    response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```